# Spark dataframe cast decimal(33,16) to float issue

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have numeric(33,16) in the database. It values are line `25.55`, `26.4343` etc.
When I am converting this to spark dataframe, it is getting converted to decimal and the values are converted to `25.5500000000000000` and `26.4343000000000000`. It is adding zero till the 16 places after decimal.

I need to cast these as float. When I cast this as float, it is changing as `25.5499999999999999999` etc.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spark's **round** function. More information regarding that can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#round(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20int))!